# customize a CButtonColumn with an Html link

Tags: php, html, gridview, yii, cbuttoncolumn

I use CButtonColumn look like this:

```
array('header'=>'Operations',
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'template'=>'{view}{update}',
'buttons'=>array
('view' => array
('url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Unit/view", array("id"=>$data->Id))',),
```

It works fine, but instead of this page I want to display another page

This one

```
  echo CHtml::link($data->project->Title, 
   'http://www.****.***/en/unit_detail/'.$data->Id, );
```

How can I insert this Html link in a CButtonColumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use properties [viewButtonUrl, viewButtonLabel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn)

```
array('header'=>'Operations',
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{view}{update}',
    'viewButtonUrl'=>'"http://www.****.***/en/unit_detail/".$data->Id'
    ....
```

Comment: but i want to insert this limk 'http://www.****.***/en/unit_detail/' not 'Yii::app()->createUrl("Unit/view", this one already works

Comment: 'viewButtonUrl'=>'"http://www.****.***/en/unit_detail/".$data->Id' this shuld work too

Comment: one more thing please if you don't minde, how can i make the view page open in a new tab or window ?

Comment: Add in array 'viewButtonOptions'=>['target'=>'_blank']

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
'buttons'=>array
('view' => array
(
'label'=>'$data->project->Title',
'url'=>'urlencode("http://www.****.***/en/unit_detail/$data->Id")',
'imageUrl'=> false),
```

Comment: thak you for the reply. but i have this error msg Undefined variable: data

Comment: updated my answer. Check the url portion.. wrap the $data inside the single quote

Comment: now the gridview apears but it shows anothoer error msg

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\wamp\www\****\domains\*****\public_html\brochure\framework\base\CComponent.php(606) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: sorry I don't understand (im a beginner) can you please explain me thank you

Comment: thank you it almost done, but when I click on the button it shows a 404 Not found page, why ??

Comment: The you must check the url if it exists or not... the url is incorrect